# Snow Leopard Airport Join preferred device-based network

Tags: snow-leopard, network, airport

Is it possible to auto-join device-based networks on Snow Leopard (i.e. preferred)?

For example, by device-based network, I mean either a printer or an ad-hoc network.

Comment: The networks created by a standalone device, like a printer, are usually ad-hoc networks. What do you mean by auto-join? Do you want your computer to connect to it automatically when it is available?

Comment: Yes, I want to automatically connect to it when it is available.

Comment: I don’t have a copy of Snow Leopard, but I just tried on Mountain Lion and it works. So, there is a strong possibility it will  work on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I still can't get it to work in Snow Leopard, even if I manually add the network to my preferred list.